# CocoaPods Pod install weird behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I am currently trying to install these Pods in my Xcode project but am getting the following screen when I try `pod install`. I have been getting this message in xCode when trying to run my project so I thought I would just try and re-install pods. But get the error below.

[image]

```
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'GooglePlacesAutocomplete'
pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift2'
pod 'DropDown'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
```

When I run `pod install` I get the following message on screen in the terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Cocoapods v0.39 you need to define a target for your pods

```
target :'nameOfTheScheme' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'GooglePlacesAutocomplete'
  pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift2'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
end
```